# Get originally purchased app version in iOS

Tags: ios, ios6, receipt, rmstore

I already read some threads about this but didn't come to a satisfying solution.

I want to receive the original app version (from the time the user downloaded the app) pre and post iOS7. In iOS7 one can decode the bundle receipt. But what about iOS6 and before?

At this time I'm using [RMStore](https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore/tree/master/RMStore/Optional), but I wasn't able to locate a (sandbox?) receipt. How do I do this?

Comment: This information isn't available prior to iOS 7. iOS 7 lets you get this information from the receipt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to do this **in iOS 6 or lower** is to store the app version in the Keychain and/or user defaults during the first run of the app. Even then, it wouldn't cover all possible scenarios.

If you didn't, you might be using libraries that do this for you (e.g.: [iVersion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion)).

Comment: Come to think about it, it would have been a nice addition to RMStore.